# Does block number increase when a slot has no proposed block?

Tags: proof-of-stake, blocks, chain-reorganization, slots, epoch

If a slot has no proposed block (ie an empty slot), does the block number still increase?

Comment: For context, I'm asking because I want to process blocks only after they have been finalized and are safe from re-org. So I want to wait 2 epochs, aka 64 slots, aka what I believe to be 64 blocks. If block numbers do not increment per slot, then my algorithm breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The explanation stems from the construction of a block in ETH2:
[image: block in eth2]

The block number you're referring to is a field of the execution layer section of the block. This part of the block has little to no knowledge of the consensus layer part, meaning no info on the slot.

For instance, no block was proposed at slot [6999138](https://beaconcha.in/slot/6999138). During the previous slot [(slot 6999137)](https://beaconcha.in/slot/6999137), a block was proposed, and in the execution layer part, the block number field is `Block Number: 17813586`.
After the missed slot, at slot [6999139](https://beaconcha.in/slot/6999139) we find `Block Number: 17813587` even though these two blocks are two slots apart.